# Combine Two Select Tag values in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select Tags and a text box.

```
<select name="select1">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="text box">
```

I want to show the values of the two select tags(select1 & select2) in the text box when a button is clicked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: Did you put any effort to do this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you want the jQuery version :)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select1" name="select1">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="select2">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="text1" name="text box">
<button onclick="combine()">ClickMe</button>

<script>
function combine() {
  $('#text1').val($('#select1').val() + $('#select2').val())
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var combineBtn =  document.getElementById("combine");

combineBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
    var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");
    var valueSelect1 = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].text;
    var valueSelect2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("text").value = valueSelect1 + valueSelect2;
});
```

```html
<select id="select1" name="select1">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="select2">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

<input type="number" id="text" name="text box">
<button id="combine">Combine</button>
```